# bottom line points coordination ContentControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to find the angle of the 2 points shown below. It is content control. Basically I want to find out if the content element has been rotated. The problem is I cant get the points correctly. Angle calculation wont be a problem. I jusy cant get point coordinates right.Any help will be appreciated.

[image: linepoints]

```
Point p1 = new Point(Convert.ToDouble(ctrl1.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)),
                                               Convert.ToDouble(ctrl1.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) + ctrl1.ActualHeight);


Point p2 = new Point(Convert.ToDouble(ctrl1.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)) + ctrl1.ActualWidth,
                                              Convert.ToDouble(ctrl1.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty))+ctrl1.ActualHeight);
```

the code above gives me Y the same all the time.
Following function will give me the angle.

```
const double Rad2Deg = 180.0 / Math.PI;
        const double Deg2Rad = Math.PI / 180.0;

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates angle in radians between two points and x-axis.
        /// </summary>
        private double Angle(Point start, Point end)
        {
            return Math.Atan2(start.Y - end.Y, end.X - start.X) * Rad2Deg;
        }
```

Comment: do you use a transformation to rotate the icon ? if so you need relative point and not the point in the transformed area

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I just enable the control, ( Selector.SetIsSelected(child, true);) and it enables the rotation

Comment: There is certainly a `RotateTransform` or `MatrixTransform` applied to either the ContentControl itself or its Content, if that is a UIElement. Try to get that transform object and thus the rotation angle directly. Your current approach won't work.